# Deriving the angular frequency in terms of period

Tags: harmonic-oscillator

In many Pre-Calculus and Trigonometry classes, when first learning about sine and cosine waves, you learn the following equations:

$$y=A\sin B(x+C)+D \tag{1}$$
$$y=A\cos B(x+C)+D \tag{2}$$

From Physics for Scientists and Engineers 3rd Edition by Douglas C. Giancoli, the equations are 
$$x=A\cos(\omega t+\phi) \tag{3}$$
$$y=A\sin(\omega t+\phi) \tag{4}$$
which are derived by finding the general solution to the the equation of motion $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+\frac{k}{m}x=0$. Nonetheless they still are of the form of equations (1) and (2) save for that they are functions of the parameter $t$ and seem to be simplified a bit.

My questions are how to derive the equation for $B=\frac{2\pi}{T}$, where $T$ is equal to  period, using equations(1) and (2). As you can already tell, $\omega$ acts as the same thing as $B$, except in physics it has some more physical significance as it is the angular frequency. Therefore by distributing $B$ of (1) and (2) into the arguments will yield $(Bx+BC)$. This leads me to wonder if $\phi$ absorb $\omega$ which is why it does not appear when $\omega$ is distributed into the arguments of sine and cosine in equations (3) and (4).

I know it is a little trivial but it seems difficult to derive period without some level of background knowledge on where to start with definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In$$x=A\cos(\omega t+\phi)$$
$\phi$ is not the left shift by $\phi$ radians, it actually is the left shift by $\dfrac{\phi}{\omega}$ radians. You can see it by factoring $\omega$:
$$x=A\cos(\omega(t+\dfrac{\phi}{\omega}))$$

$T$ is the *time* taken for $1$ revolution, so there will be $\dfrac{1}{T}$ revolutions in $1$ second.
Since there are $2\pi$ radians in $1$ revolution, there will be $2\pi \times \dfrac{1}{T}$ radians in $1$ second. This constant quantity with units *radians per second* is called *angular frequency* $\omega$.

---

$f(t)=\cos(t)$ graph has a period of $2\pi$ seconds.
$f(\omega t)$ *compresses* the graph of $f(t)$ by a factor of $\omega$ when $\omega\gt 1$.
Thus the period of $f(\omega t) = \cos(\omega t)$ also gets *reduced* by the same factor and becomes $\dfrac{2\pi}{\omega}$ seconds.

Comment: I don't think your first sentence is phrased correctly. If $t$ has units of seconds, $\frac{\phi}{\omega}$ would also have units of seconds, not radians.